# Samba 100 Users

Tags: samba, users

I teach a class and would like to give 150 students their own folder and have each student's folder secure and accessible by only the student and myself.

Is it possible to set up a Samba share with a user name/password, have students/users only able to access their own folders, and do so without that share being linked to a system user account?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: May I ask why you want to avoid creating Linux user accounts? You could just create them and then lock them - which should not affect Samba login.

Comment: My belief, from what I could piece together from the various online sources I found, was that the Samba users only approach was possible and easier. Unfortunately, I don't take good notes while surfing around, often move on to other work and take too long to come back to the problem. I end up forgetting what I found and have to start over again.

I would have no problem adding system users if there was a way to add them all at once rather than one at a time. I'd rather spend 15 minutes rather than an hour or two adding users.